# Segmenting an SQL statement using R

Tags: sql, regex, r

I'm new to R and reg-ex but recently decided to take it up
I'm trying to do something which I'm sure should be very simple

I have 2 SQL statements that i have randomly created using two methods. Both are set up differently

The first statement uses Aliases for the table names
The second statement uses  full names for tables

I have two questions

I want to get a script in R that will remove all the aliases and replace them with the full table name based on the From clause e.g.

```
SELECT AL1.attr1,AL1.attr2
FROM Table_1 as AL1
```

Would be turned into

```
SELECT Table_1.attr1,Table_1.attr2
FROM Table_1
```

As a second part of my little experiment, I want to be able to segment the fields using regex so for example only selecting **AL1.attr1,AL1.attr2** and putting them in a column and a second column would have **Table_1 as AL1**

I think the second part will almost answer the first part

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without regex:

```
require(stringr); require(R.oo)
processMySQLtxt = function(txt)
{
  fromSplit = sapply(strsplit(txt,"FROM")[[1]],trim)
  tableInfo = trim(strsplit(fromSplit[2],"as")[[1]])
  tableName = tableInfo[1]
  aliasTable = tableInfo[2]
  originallySelectedNames = strsplit(fromSplit[1],"SELECT ")[[1]][2]  
  selectInfo = lapply(strsplit(originallySelectedNames,","),trim)[[1]]  
  newStatement = if(!is.na(aliasTable)) 
                    paste("SELECT ",paste(sapply(selectInfo, str_replace_all, pattern=aliasTable, replacement=tableName),collapse=","), " FROM ", tableName, sep="")
                 else
                   paste("SELECT ",paste(selectInfo,collapse=","), " FROM ", tableName, sep="")  
  return(data.frame("Originally"=originallySelectedNames, "OriginalTableAlias" = fromSplit[2], "newStatement" = newStatement))
}
txt= "SELECT AL1.attr1,AL1.attr2 FROM Table_1 as AL1"
processMySQLtxt(txt)
txt= "SELECT attr1,attr2 FROM Table_1"
processMySQLtxt(txt)
```

just `(s/l)apply` the function to your collection of statements. You can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` or `do.call("rbind",results)` to bring it all together.

Comment: @ Hans Roggeman This is amazing, I need to probably go through the R documentation a little bit more to understand the sapply function but I understand the most part. A final question on this. What if there are no aliases so for example SELECT attr1,attr2
FROM Table_1. Both would be fed into your function and the full aliasing would need to be done in both. So if i put both SQLs into the function it would return the same answer for both?

Comment: You just need to check for `NA` on the aliasTable if that is the case - function changed in original post.

Comment: Final thing on this, Is it possible to use the strsplit function to split on 2 words so for example a WHERE clause if it exists. Im trying to make the function as robust as possible

Comment: The split can be any regular expression: `strsplit("SELECT AL1.attr1,AL1.attr2 FROM Table_1 as AL1 WHERE AL1.attr1 == 1",split="WHERE|FROM|SELECT")`. try `?strplit` to get help on the function. If you are new to R you should get a decent IDE - try RStudio, Eclipse with StatET, Rkward or Revolution R.